# Can an adaptive card used in an adaptive dialog in a templated fashion?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards, adaptive-dialogs

I would like to return an Adaptive card via SendActivity in an Adaptive Dialog.

The code to do this looks like:

```
new OnIntent("Help")
{
    Actions = new List<Dialog>()
    {
        new SendActivity("${Help-Root-Dialog()}")
    }
},
```

But, I'd like to include a parameter in the call to create the adaptive card. Let's say a username (and therefore personalize the message to the user. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: OK, as I've read more in the space, I've learnt I can use SetProperty() to provide a property I want the adaptive card to show and then reference that property in the card's definition. 
Literally, $(user.name) for example.

Comment: Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: While looking at the "AdaptorWithErrorHandler" middleware, stumbled upon this: 
                // Send a catch-all apology to the user.
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(ActivityFactory.FromObject(
                    _templates.Evaluate("SomethingWentWrong", exception)));
Which is passing a param into the template specified by language generator. This might be it!

Comment: I don't understand how that's related to your question. Are you saying you still need help?

Comment: Will put an answer based on what I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a few ways to do this:

1. Use SetProperty before the card is invoked in the conversation

```
new SetProperty()
{
    Property = "conversation.gameCreateDate",
    Value = DateTime.Now.ToString()
},

new SendActivity("${PlayGameCard()}"),
//In .lg file:
# PlayGameCard
[Activity
    Attachments = ${json(AdaptiveCard.Definition())}
]

//...
{
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "spacing": "None",
    "text": "Created ${conversation.gameCreateDate}",
    "isSubtle": true,
    "wrap": true
}
//...
```

2. Send a parameter when calling the card, as is done in the AdaptorWithErrorHandler middleware.

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(ActivityFactory.FromObject( _templates.Evaluate("SomethingWentWrong", exception)));
```

I used option 1, but 2 seems to be the way.